# Proving the set of functions from $N \longrightarrow N$, when $f(n) \neq n$ for every $n \in N$ is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to to prove that the cardinality of the set of all functions from $N \longrightarrow N$, when $f(n) \neq n$ for every $n \in N$ is more than $א_0$, using the diagonal lemma. How can it be done?

Comment: Note that the word "group" has a very specific meaning in math, so you likely mean another word for that.

Comment: @Mark why doesn't it fit here?

Comment: It doesn't fit because a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) is likely not what you are referring to in your question.

Comment: @wgrenard Understood, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create any countable  list of such functions as  $\{f_i\}$.

Create a function $g$ so that $g(k) \ne k$ and $g(k) \ne f_k(k)$[$*$].

And....

[$*$] for example you could say $g(k) = f_k(k) + k + 1$.

Comment: Also could you explain further how does your answer solve the problem?

Comment: For every $k$, $g_k(k) \neq f_i$ and thus this set is uncountable?

Comment: There's only one $g$ there is not $g_k$ and if there were $g_k(k)$ would a value-- not a a function.  But $g \ne f_i$ for any $i$ (as $g(i) \ne f_i9i)$).  So $g$ is not in the set.  So the set is not complete.  So no countable set is complete.  And the complete set is not countable.

Comment: "Also could you explain further how does your answer solve the problem?"  And spoil all your fun?  I assume you have seen Cantor's diagonal argument at least once in your life.

Answer (score 0):

If it were countable, by the Diagonal lemma there would exist a function (in particular the plus one of the diagonal function) that was not listed hence the entire list of fixed-point free functions is not a countable list.

Comment: Notice that you could create continuum many such functions not listed by adding any constant to any diagonal entry, an entire Baire space of functions.

Comment: "in particular the plus one of the diagonal function"  minor nitpick:  If $f_k(k) = k-1$ then $g(k) = f_k(k) = k$.  Of course there are an infinite number of other values to pick; any $n$ but $k$ and $f_k(k)$.